# Can we create pie chart and scatter plot combined using highcharts.js?

Tags: highcharts

This question is regarding highcharts. Can we create something like this in highcharts? Pie chart on a scatter plot? Please have a look at the url    https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcmzn0t0hz4s2x7/pieChartScatterPlot.png

Answer (score 2):

I would draw a normal scatter plot first, then loop the points placing additional pie charts on top of them:

```
// initial scatter
series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'Scatter Me',
    data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
}]

// in load event, loop our scatter series
// and add a pie chart at each point
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function(){
            var chart = this;
            $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i,datap){
                chart.addSeries({
                    type: 'pie',
                    minSize: 50,
                    size: 50,
                    dataLabels: {enabled: false},
                    data: [Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10],
                    center: [datap.plotX-21, datap.plotY-21],
                }, false);
            });
            chart.redraw();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k5Hf/) and how it looks:

[image]

The one thing that's got me scratching my head is that I had to introduce a `fudge factor` to get the pie center to align with the points.